# RSS/Atom feed for medium.com blog tag

Tags: rss, medium

Like most blogging platforms, medium.com provides RSS feeds, though in [a rather broken way](https://medium.com/@cogdog/medium-your-rss-feeds-are-mess-ebfe6f731c22).

I found feeds:

- for all a user writes, in the form https://medium.com/feed/@aubreymcfato/;
- for all posts by any user in a blog, in the form https://medium.com/feed/opensensorsdata-review/;
- for all posts by any user with a specific tag, in the form https://medium.com/feed/tag/wikipedia/.

But how to subscribe to a subset of a blog/user, as defined by a tag? I tried various URL combinations and they didn't work.

Comment: I hope I'm not forced to use screenscraping intermediaries like http://www.feed43.com/ as someone suggests.

Answer (score 2):

As of Feb 2016 the answer is it's not possible. You've identified all of the RSS options that Medium.com provides.

Indeed, since you first wrote it's becoming harder to identify Medium's RSS support. It would not be surprising if they drop their limited support as their internal user base grows (as did Twitter and (largely) Facebook).

Comment: Indeed it seems the RSS support may be getting worse, per Nikitonsky, *[Medium is a poor choice for blogging](https://medium.com/@nikitonsky/medium-is-a-poor-choice-for-blogging-bb0048d19133)*:

> But the misadventures do not end here. If anyone decides to blog on Medium regularly, there’s no way to follow them through RSS. I mean Medium does serve RSS, but they serve it with replies and it turns the whole idea into a non-usable mess. You just get random phrases with no context in your feed instead of articles

Answer (score 0):

You can now actually get a feed of all posts on a given blog with a given tag. The proper URL for this would be: **https://medium.com/feed/BLOG/tagged/TAG**

Careful, as of today, it seems to work for shared publications, but not for a specific user. Thus, it looks like you still **can NOT** do this: https://medium.com/feed/@USER/tagged/TAG.

Source: [Medium RSS feeds documentation](https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/214874118-RSS-feeds)